# How to properly use system in C

Tags: c, cygwin

I'm trying to open Google's Chrome with C.

I'm using Cygwin bash as my terminal and have added it to my PATH - here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (void)
{
    system(" C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe ");
    return 0;
}
```

Yesterday I had the problem of an error showing "sh: Start: Command not found" when putting "Start" in front of the google file path.

Today, after taking out the "Start" and just leaving the file path, I'm getting the errors:

```
sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
sh: -c: line 0: ` C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe '
```

I replaced the file path of google for:

```
system("notepad");
```

and it pulls up notepad no problem.

I compile using gcc then run the executable with ./a.exe

I'm completely lost - any advice?

***NOTE***
This is the first time asking a question here, so if I missed any valuable info please let me know

Comment: Looks like there's an unescaped space in that file path.

Comment: I would argue that using system itself is improper, but if you do and you have a path with spaces in it you must put quotes around that path. `"\"<path>\""`

Comment: To avoid escaping backslashes, use `Cygwin` syntax for path (as in `/cygdrive/c/.../.../`)

Comment: One of the problems in your code (it's not the only one): You are running `sh` here, but use backslashes as path separator. This is not understood by POSIX shell. In POSIX shell, the path separator is a forward slash. You would see the same effect, if you copy and paste your command into a `sh` command line.

Answer (score 2):

```
-- system(" C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe ");
++ system("\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe\"");
```

Recall that spaces, by default, are delimiters and separators that divide different parts of the command line.  With your original command, your command line was parsed as:

```
argv[0] : C:\Program
argv[1] : Files
argv[2] : (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
```

In otherwords, it was trying to execute program `C:\Program`, with arguments `Files` and `(x86)\Google....`.

By adding quotes around it, you are telling the shell (likely `CMD` in your case) that you are ***not*** trying to execute `C:\Program` with two arguments.

Instead, the quotes clarify that you want to execute
 `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"` as one big path to executable, including the spaces and parens within the name.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Just saved me from lots of headaches lol

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the backslashes and do a

```
system("'C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe'")
```

or a

```
system("'/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe'")
```